# python pandas df.to_excel is not working properly only output one line

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I want to write to Excel. But all I got is just only one line.
It supposed to output 10 line, because I have 10 excel file.
If I run the code bellow, outcome is always 10th file.
Here is my code.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os 

directory = root/hoge1/

for(filename,f) in zip(os.listdir(directory), glob.glob(root/hoge2)
  if(filename.endswith(".xlsx") and filename.find("abc")==-1):
   all_data = pd.DataFrame()
   f = pd.read_excel(f,engine="openyxl", usecols = [4],skiprows = 1)
   f = f.fillna("")
   data = f.T

   filname_pref = [filename[:2]]
   filname_mun = [filename[:6]]
   filname_mun = [filename[3:] for filename in filename_mun]

   data.insert(0,"aiueo", filename_pref)
   data.insert(0,"aiueo", filename_mun)
   
   all_data = all_data.append(data, igonre_index = True)

all_data.to_excel("output.xlsx", sheet_name = 'sheet_name_1', index = False)
```

Thank you a lot :)

Comment: If I print(all_data), output are 10files. So directly is totally ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cross-check whether there are 10 excels and also the content of those excel files as specified in your directory **'root/hoge2'.**

These should satisfy the **conditions** specified in the code.

** If you print(all_data) it will print a Dataframe that should ideally contain 0-9 index entries [total 10 rows] and column names on top.

** If possible share a snippet of the print output

Comment: >If you print(all_data) it will print a Dataframe that should ideally contain 0-9 index entries [total 10 rows] and column names on top.

Yes.it does.

Comment: >If possible share a snippet of the print output
umm, I think problem is a Indenting the end of code... anyway I suppose I should give up.
so thanks anyway.

Comment: @Takahiro indenting might not be the problem, if you indent this **'all_data.to_excel()'** you will get 1 excel since the name given is same **'output.xlsx'** but with only the last for loop iteration data.

Comment: Before giving up I would suggest moving this **all_data = pd.DataFrame()** line of code outside the for loop, as it initializes a **new** dataframe for **every iteration** losing the previous iterations data.

Comment: Sir, as you mentioned, I tried to moving all_data = pd.DataFrame() line of code outside the for loop. then, code works totally fine as I hope!!! I was so sutupid, but thank you so much Sir. I really appreciate.